# how to work multiusers on one database

Tags: android, sql, eclipse

i am creating simple android apps like student registration.

suppose i registered three students data in mobile.(insert data).

then how all teachers can see student list. all teachers have same application install.

Thanks.

Comment: I am confused.Are you talking about data saved on the mobile database?then that can be accessed only by that mobile phone since there is no web based API involved.So if you do not use an external to android API,this is not possible

Comment: confusion is that i have already created full application with mobile database now what?

Answer (score 0):

It is common for applications to offer features such as backup storage, data sync, data sharing etc. Building stand alone applications that only function and save their data on the device they are installed on is at times not feasible. A backend is usually needed where data can be saved and manipulated for the app to provide the service it was intended for.

Building this requires time, a different skill set and other resources (e.g. servers, push notification services, etc). Fortunately, there are several platforms that provide ready-made customizable backends that you can integrate with your apps. These are known as ‘Backend as a Service’, or BaaS in short.
we are going to look at using Parse to provide a backend for an Android application. We’ll briefly look at what it offers before building an application that will use it for user registration, authentication and storing of user data.
you can follow this link to learn more :

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cloud-backend-android-app-using-parse/

or You can see :

http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/